# Hide div if status code is not 200 with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe which is calling a dynamic external url based on a material number. In general when a page is not available to be loaded in the iframe the response is 403.

In this case I would like to hide the outer div (iframe-container) with Java Script.

```
<div class="iframe-container">
<iframe src="url-to-not-existing-page"></iframe>
</div>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you have access to the other domain? If not, I doubt it, due to cross-domain security restrictions

Comment: Not going to be doable since you can not read 3rd party domain.

Comment: Yes I have access to the other domain

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the div if the status is different than 200, by changing the display style, in your Javascript you can accomplish with the following code, just have to pass the dynamic url to a function that will check the avaiability of the url. Please change it to your case of use:

```
function checkImage(url) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.send();
  request.onload = function() {
    status = request.status;
    if (request.status == 200) //if(statusText == OK) {
      const outerDiv = document.querySelector('.iframe-container')
      outerDiv.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
      const outerDiv = document.querySelector('.iframe-container')
      outerDiv.style.display = 'hidden' // or 'none'
    }
  }
}

checkImage("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I am getting the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'const' 
Would you have any suggestion?